# Reverse a multidimensional array 4 times

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

For a simple game, I need a scoreboard that is generated dynamically on startup. This scoreboard is stored as an multidimensional array in C#. Generating the base scores isn't that hard, but the problem is that this array should be reversed 4 times as shown below.

The multidimensional array:

```
int[,] scoreBoard = new int[4, 4];
```

The base figures:

```
    {
      5,  10,  15,  20
     10,  15,  20,  25
     15,  20,  25,  30
    }
```

Should become:

```
    {
      5,  10,  15,  20,  20,  15,  10,   5
     10,  15,  20,  25,  25,  20,  15,  10
     15,  20,  25,  30,  30,  25,  20,  15
     15,  20,  25,  30,  30,  25,  20,  15
     10,  15,  20,  25,  25,  20,  15,  10
      5,  10,  15,  20,  20,  15,  10,   5
}
```

Comment: How does reversing an array yields more elements :? Also you shown 3x4 array not 4x4

Comment: He means transform it. The output is reflected horizontal and vertical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = ArrayReflection(scoreBoard);       

public static T[,] ArrayReflection<T>(T[,] arr)
{
    // number of rows in array
    int m = arr.GetLength(0);
    // number of columns in array
    int n = arr.GetLength(1);
    var res = new T[m*2, n*2];

    for(int r=0; r<m; r++)
        for(int c=0; c<n; c++)
    {
        res[r,c] = arr[r,c];
        res[r,n + c] = arr[r, n - c - 1];
        res[r + m,c] = arr[m - r - 1, c];
        res[r+m,n+c] = arr[m - r - 1, n - c - 1];   
    }

    return res;     
}
```

Comment: Agree with this solution, but it leaves me wishing `C#` was more like `Fortran`. This would have been a 1 liner in fortran.